# Save and Restore Tensorflow Graph in same Python Session

Tags: python, tensorflow, save, restore

There are several related questions about this but none seem to address the specific issue I have.

I wrote some code which saves and restores a TensorFlow model. If I save the model and restore the model in subsequent python runs everything is okay. However, if I try to save and restore the model in the same Python instance, I get the following error:

```
TypeError: Cannot interpret feed_dict key as Tensor: Tensor Tensor("Foo/X:0", shape=(?, 4), dtype=float32) is not an element of this graph.
```

As far as I can see the variable "Foo/X" is in the graph after restore by looking at:

```
[n.name for n in tf.get_default_graph().as_graph_def().node]
```

The basic idea of my code is to create/re-create the graph with identical calls to the TensorFlow API then to use tf.train.Saver().restore() to restore the trained state. A simplified example which gives the same error *(on the last line of function Barfoo)*:

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

def Foobar():
    global R1
    with tf.variable_scope('Foo'):
        X = tf.placeholder("float", [None, 4], name = 'X')
        Y = tf.placeholder("float", [None], name = 'Y')
        W = tf.Variable(tf.ones([4, 1]), name = 'W')
        YH = tf.matmul(X, W, name = 'YH')
        L = tf.reduce_sum(tf.nn.l2_loss(YH - Y), name = 'L')
        O = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate = 0.001, name = 'O').minimize(L)
        init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
    S.run(init)
    for i in range(32):
        l1, _ = S.run([L, O], feed_dict = {X: x, Y: y})
        print(str(l1))
    R1 = S.run(YH, feed_dict = {X: np.ones((1, 4))})
    saver = tf.train.Saver()
    saver.save(S, "TFModel/savemodel")

def Barfoo():  
    global R2
    with tf.variable_scope('Foo'):
        X = tf.placeholder("float", [None, 4], name = 'X')
        Y = tf.placeholder("float", [None], name = 'Y')
        W = tf.Variable(tf.ones([4, 1]), name = 'W')
        YH = tf.matmul(X, W, name = 'YH')
        L = tf.reduce_sum(tf.nn.l2_loss(YH - Y), name = 'L')
        O = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate = 0.001, name = 'O').minimize(L)
    saver = tf.train.Saver()
    saver.restore(S, tf.train.latest_checkpoint('TFModel/'))
    print(str([n.name for n in tf.get_default_graph().as_graph_def().node]))
    R2 = S.run(YH, feed_dict = {X: np.ones((1, 4))})

x = np.random.rand(32, 4)
y = x.sum(axis = 1) + np.random.rand(32) / 10
S = tf.Session()
R1, R2 = None, None     
Foobar()
tf.reset_default_graph()
Barfoo()
print('R1: ' + str(R1))
print('R2: ' + str(R2)
```

**Why does this code give an error on trying to use the variable X in Barfoo?** And why does it work if I first run *Foobar*, terminate the program, and then run *Barfoo*?

Answer (score 0):

Answering the question in bold, which is:

**Why does this code give an error on trying to use the variable X in Barfoo?**

With S.run, you are expecting the name of the tensor that you want to calculate, and a dictionary for feed_dict with tensor names as keys. You are trying to pass the tensor objects themselves as keys, instead of their names. Compare:

WRONG)

```
R2 = S.run(YH, feed_dict = {X: np.ones((1, 4))})
```

RIGHT)

```
R2 = S.run("Foo/YH:0", feed_dict={"Foo/X:0": np.ones((1, 4))})
```

Notice that I am informing the names of the tensors, and not the tensors themselves (as it is done in your version). Just changing the lines above is enough to have the code working.

As regarding the second question, please be a bit more clear about how to reproduce it, so I can check what is going on.